# Sequence of sets and neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a Hausdorff topological space $X$ and some point $x\in X$.
Suppose we have a sequence $(E_n)_{n\geq 0}$ of sets such that $\{x\}\subset ...\subset E_n\subset E_{n-1}\subset ...E_0$ and $\bigcap_{n\geq 0}E_n=\{x\}$.

Is it possible to say that every neighborhood of $x$ contains one (hence many) set $E_n$? What is the precise argument?

Comment: What about $E_n=\{0\}\cup (n+1,\infty)$ in $\Bbb R$  with the usual topology?

Comment: [abc](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381609/a-n-is-decreasing-to-a-singleton-do-all-neighborhoods-of-the-singleton-conta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\Bbb R$ let $$E_n=\left(\leftarrow,-2^n\right]\cup\left[-\frac1{2^n},\frac1{2^n}\right]\cup[2^n,\to)$$ for $n\ge 0$. Then $\bigcap_{n\ge 0}E_n=\{0\}$, but clearly no bounded nbhd of $0$ contains any of the $E_n$.

The same idea could be simplified, of course: for instance, you could replace each centre block by $\{0\}$ and throw away each left wing. (I just liked the picture.) In fact, using the same basic idea you can build an example in any space $X$ that has a point $x$ with an open nbhd $U$ such that $X\setminus U$ is infinite.

Answer (score 3):

No, in general it's not true. Imagine $\Bbb R^2$ with the topology generated by all *horizontal open intervals*, and let $E_n$ be the standard disk of radius $1/n$.

Comment: Much better example than mine! :-)

Comment: What are the horizontal open intervals please?

Comment: @Gob: Sets of the form $(a,b)\times\{0\}$ for $a,b\in\Bbb R,$ $a<b.$

Comment: No, I meant $(a,b)\times\{x\}$ for $a,b,x\in\Bbb R,\,a<b$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where $\{x\}$ is open...

Comment: True, I should have considered a Hausdorff space. I edit my post accordingly.

Comment: @Gob: Hausdorff spaces can still have isolated points.

Comment: Yes but, still, in Hausdorff space all singletons are closed, aren't they?

Comment: @Gob: Singletons are closed in $T_1$-spaces, in fact.

Comment: @Gob: However, sets can be open and closed at the same time. For an extreme example of this, consider $X$ under the [discrete topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_topology), which is Hausdorff, and in which every subset of $X$ is both closed and open in $X.$