# $A_n$ is decreasing to a singleton. Do all neighborhoods of the singleton, contain almost all $A_n$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a locally compact Hausdorff [homogeneous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space) topological space and $(A_n)$ be a decreasing sequence of subsets of $X$ and
$$\bigcap_{n}A_n=\{a\}$$
be a singleton.

Is there some $n$ for which $A_n$ is contained in any compact neighborhood of $a$?:
$$(\forall U\text{: neighborhood of } a)(\exists n\in \Bbb N)(A_n\subseteq U)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if $X=\Bbb R$ with the standard topology and $A_n=\{0\}\cup[n,\infty)$?

Answer (score 4):

No. Try $A_n\subset\mathbb C$ made of the complex numbers $r\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}$ with $r\geqslant0$ and $t$ in $(0,1/n)$.